# USB device opens Applications, then types in text field

Tags: macos, terminal, usb

I got a letter in the mail that contained a small USB device. Here is what it loks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhO7R.jpg

[image]

When I plug it into my computer it seems to hover over the programs in my Dock and then opens one. It then types a link into a text field that is available. I originally had Skype in the dock and it defaulted to that one, strange. I removed Skype from the dock and now it opens to System Preferences.

Here's a video of what happens as I plug it in: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yuw6ggvo77rkvwh/Test1MysteryDevice.mov

Also, it does not appear like a memory stick does on my computer. I can't seem to locate it when it's plugged in. It would be cool if I could find it somehow. It would be even cooler if I could program it to do something I wanted.

Thanks, and if anyone can help out that's awesome or if you could point me to a forum/anywhere that might be able to help out, that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it self-identifies as a HID (Human Interface Device), specifically a keyboard. As soon as it is accepted as a keyboard by the OS it can send any sequence of keystrokes, and the OS will assume that it is input from a human user.

Answer (score 0):

Scripting such behavior is easy using [Applescript](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/).

However automatically running a program from a USB stick when it is inserted is supposed to be impossible on OS X, as auto-run is a security risk.

Of course at the very least a custom USB device could be made to act like a mouse and keyboard, so even without autorun it's a risk to plug strange devices into your computer.

---

To get more info on the device you can go to System Profiler and look for the device on the USB bus.

If it is a custom device pretending to be a keyboard then it's probably hardwired to do what it does, and you probably won't be able to reprogram it; you'd need to find a manufacturer that will sell you customized devices.

Comment: Okay, how would I go about finding the file related to the device? I know it's not a security risk because it was sent from the University of Waterloo

Comment: @SirKaydian Well the mail you got _says_ it's from U of Waterloo ;) In this case you're almost certainly correct that the device is safe, but it is theoretically a risk. -- To get more info on the device you can go to System Profiler and look for the device on the USB bus. If it is a custom device pretending to be a keyboard then it's probably hardwired to do what it does, and you probably won't be able to reprogram it; you'd need to find a manufacturer that will sell you customized devices.

Comment: @SirKaydian Yeah, I didn't think it was you. Unfortunately there's no way I can direct my comment at the anonymous downvoter.